# Python3 adds extra byte when printing hex values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have run into a strange difference between Python2 and Python3. Printing the same list of characters yields an extra byte C2 when printed with Python3. I would have expected the same behaviour. Python2 behaves as I expected. What am I missing here?

```
$ python3 -c "print('\x30\xA0\x04\x08')" | xxd
0000000: 30c2 a004 080a     
$ python2 -c "print('\x30\xA0\x04\x08')" | xxd
0000000: 30a0 0408 0a
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python 3 strings are unicode, and on your platform unicode is printed using UTF-8 encoding. The UTF-8 encoding for unicode character U+00A0 is 0xC2 0xA0, which is what you see.

Python 2 strings are bytestrings, so they are output exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped. I did not see the issue with U+00A0.

Answer (score 8):

In Python 3 all string literals are unicode.

`\A0` converted to UTF-8 is a [`no-break space`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space):

> `U+00A0`   no-break space (HTML `&#160`; `·` `&nbsp;`) Can be encoded in UTF-8 as `C2 A0`

Try this:

```
$ python3 -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x30\xA0\x04\x08')" | xxd
0000000: 30a0 0408                                0...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped. I did not see the issue with U+00A0.